# Cholesky decomposition vs. $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ decomposition

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

In different books and on Wikipedia, you can see frequent mentions of Cholesky decomposition and $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ decomposition is seldom mentioned. Why so? As far as I understand, $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ decomposition can be applied to a broader range of matrices (we don't need a matrix to be positive-definite) and for the same computational price.

Comment: For symmetric definite positive matrices : dont hesitate, prefer Cholesky (http://www.physics.arizona.edu/~restrepo/475A/Notes/sourcea-/node66.html) which besides is very efficient, on the grounds of **stability**.

Comment: @Jean, if Cholesky works stably on a matrix (which implies positive definiteness), then $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ will work as well, while avoiding square root evaluations.

Comment: @J. M. isn't a mathematician I agree

Answer (score 3):

A frequent reason for preferring $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ over Cholesky is that the latter requires the evaluation of square roots, while the former does not. In symbolics, where one might want to keep the entries radical-free, or in numerics, where the square root operation on a particular machine might be slower than division, this can be a deciding factor.

As for positive-definiteness: it is true that $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ can work on matrices that aren't positive definite, but it is no longer guaranteed to be numerically stable. Also, without an extra operation like pivoting, $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ will fail on matrices such as

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

or in general, matrices with a singular leading submatrix.

(This got too long for a comment.)